# Logarithmic Graphing Problem

Tags: logarithms

"A population of an organism grows such that after *t* hours the number of organisms is *N* thousand, where *N* is given by the equation *N* = *A* - $8e^{-kt}$

Initially there are 3000 organisms and this number doubles after 5 hours."

Find the value of : i) *A*
                    ii) *k*

This is all I need help for currently, and I have attempted many ways. Firstly, I did a table, so that when t is 1(as it is initial), N is 3000 and then when t is 6 (5 hours later), N is 6000(doubled).

What I did next was to ln the equation, getting ln N = lnA - 8kt. Using simultaneous equations, I have:

ln 3000 = ln A - 8k and ln 6000 = ln A - 48k and this is where I'm stuck, send help D;

Comment: t=0 is the initial time. So A should be easier to calculate. Then you need to solve 2N = A - 8$e^{-5k}$, which should also be doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that N is how many thousand of organisms there are, not how many organisms there are.

At time $t=0$, $N=3$. Plugging this into your equation gives 
$$3 = A - 8e^{-0k}$$
$$3 = A - 8$$
$$A = 11$$.

At time $t=5$, $N=6$. Plugging this into your equation gives 
$$6 = 11 - 8e^{-5k}$$
$$-5 = -8e^{-5k}$$
$$e^{-5k} = \frac58$$
$$-5k = \ln\frac58$$
$$k = -\frac{1}{5}\ln\frac58$$